# CSV with Number and Slash around numbers updates the data when I open in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, escaping, slash

I am exporting a CSV file from my data and I have some data which has values like `"20 8/1"`

When I open the CSV file in Excel it just converts it to `"28"`. If I have `"500 500/10"` it will turn to `"550"` (It seems to add up the values 20 + 8/1 = 20 + 8 = 28. 500 + 500/10 = 500 + 50 = 550)

[image]

How can I avoid this?

- I am already using double quotes for each cell/column value - that
  doesnt make any difference.
- I know that we can import the data using
  "Data" > "Get Data" > "From Text/CSV." but users are not willing to make that effort.
- Another option is to export directly
  into Excel but that option does not work as CSVs are getting imported to other systems which is not accepting Excel.
- I also understand that I can do something after opening up Excel but till that time data is already converted so looking for an option where CSV itself got fixed up. Is there any way to escape the `/` or some other idea?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an age old problem. And the only non code solution is to do the "Data" > "Get Data" > "From Text/CSV." or copy paste the data and use text to columns and dictate that column as text.  Otherwise you will need to code something to do the import.  As you know once it is open in Excel the data is corrupted.

Comment: Can you insert some character inbetween your text, like `50_500/10` and filter it out after ? Yes, it will create an extra step. Alternative is to import using VBA. Why do you need to open in Excel in the first place, can't you perform same operation elsewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the export you can change the field to:

```
="20 8/1"
```

For example:

```
123,="20 8/1",456
```

This should preserve the data 'as is'.